# Why are Btrfs and others disabled in Custom Format in Disks?

Tags: 20.04, disk, btrfs

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.  I tried to format a new disk with Btrfs, but it is disabled.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't use "Disks" much. I don't think it can format a disk without making partitions on it. But you can format a disk to `btrfs` without making partitions quite easily using CLI. Is it a HDD, or a SSD?

Comment: @Pilot6 It is a virtual OS and the disk is a virtual disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need **btrfs-progs** installed to be able to create `btrfs` partitions.

You can't format a partition that is in mounted.

You need to unmount it first.

And I suggest using `gparted` instead of "Disks", it has a more clear GUI.

If this is a HDD, you can format it to `btrfs` without creating partition tables by running:

```
sudo mkfs.btrfs /dev/sdb
```

Comment: I will try to use gparted, but I did not mount it manually, and I cannot find any menu to unmount the disk in Disks. Also, if that is the reason, why does it allow formatting with Ext4?

Comment: There is a soft button with a black square to unmount.

Comment: It is an unformatted disk. Is it still mounted? I have added the screenshot at the end of the question.

Comment: It is not mounted, but it doesn't have a partition table.

Comment: I created a partition table (GPT) using Gparted, but after doing that, I clicked the [+] button and "Create Partition" dialogue popped up. Yet, in the next screens, the results were the same: Ext4 is available but Btrfs is disabled. Also, "btrfs" is disabled in the Filesystem drop-down list. Maybe, Btrfs driver or software is not installed by default on Ubuntu 20.04 and I have to install it manually?

Comment: It is installed. Maybe you can't use it on virtual disks. It is a bad idea anyway. What happens if you try to do it in CLI? BTW is `btrfs-progs` installed? If not, install it first.

Comment: I installed btrfs-progs and now Btrfs are enabled both in Disks and Gparted. I think it was the root cause that btrfs-progs is not installed by default on Ubuntu (because I certainly have no memory of having uninstalled it).

Comment: If you install a system using `btrfs`, like I do, it is installed ;-)